# subtract cells in different worksheets dependening from 2 different ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I currently try to setup a storage location. For the booking of items i use 2 Worksheets. Worksheet 1 is used to type in the Part Number ( Cell B4 ) and the Quantity ( Cell B7 ) of the items. In Worksheet 2 the actual quantity on stock ( Column D ) and part numbers ( Column A ) are saved.
The task at hand is, everytime an item needs to be booked, the user types in the part number and the quantity in Worksheet 1, clicks the button and the stock in worksheet 2 gets adjusted.
I'm totally new to vba and everything I know about it is self taught so please forgive my little knowledge to the subject.

I figured out the comparison of the values of the part numbers in Worksheet 1 and 2. The problem i cant come over with is the part where the quantity typed in Worksheet 1 is subtracted from the actual quantity on stock of the part in Worksheet 2.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim xlRange As Range
Dim xlCell As Range
Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
Dim valueToFind, Quantity


    valueToFind = Worksheets(1).Range("B4").Value
    Quantity = Worksheets(1).Range("B7").Value

    Set xlSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set xlRange = xlSheet.Range("A1:A10000")

    For Each xlCell In xlRange
        If xlCell.Value = valueToFind Then

        'Execute "Cell D in the same row as valueToFind" - Quantity'

        End If

End Sub
```

So, the Then function should work something like mentioned above. 
Every help is very much appreciated

Comment: xlrange.cells(xlRange.find(valuetoFind).row,4)

Comment: You're missing a `Next xlCell` before your `End Sub`

Comment: Hi, took a weekend off, thats why I respond that late. I added the lines you provided and the solution looks like '''  xlRange.Cells(xlRange.Find(valueToFind).Row, 4) = xlRange.Cells(xlRange.Find(valueToFind).Row, 4) - Quantity '''   , Thank you guys